# Flask 4 items per table row

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm making a table in FLASK using an array of objects. I want to display 4 objects per table row but the `batch(4)` command doesn't seem to be working properly. It runs, without error. But displays nothing as well.

```
 <table class="Fruits_n_Veggies">
        {% for item in fruit | batch(4)  %}
            {% if item.name %}
                <tr>
                    <td class = "img"> <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=item.img_url) }}" height="100"; width="100"><br>
                    {{ item.name }} {{ item.price_min }} - {{ item.price_max }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

I'd appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`batch` returns a container with 4 objects in it. You need to iterate over them as well.

```
{% for row in fruit | batch(4)  %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
            <td class = "img"> <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=item.img_url) }}" height="100"; width="100"><br>
            {{ item.name }} {{ item.price_min }} - {{ item.price_max }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```